# Repeater-does'nt display Image - problems with resovling the url

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have an aspx page which presents the data using a repeater from DS. One of the fillds in the db is a path to an image. 
I want the image itself to be displayed. I'm trying to it also with code behind in c#.

the code of the aspx:

```
   <asp:Repeater ID="ExampleRepeater" runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" onitemdatabound="ExampleRepeater_ItemDataBound" >
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>   choose
                </th>
                <th>   product is
                </th>
                <th>   products
                </th>
                <th>   price
                </th>
                <th>   des
                </th>
                <th>   path
                </th>
                <th>   pic
                </th>
            </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="checkbox1" runat="server"  
                    CausesValidation="false"></asp:CheckBox>
            </td>
            <td>

                <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductID") %>'></asp:Label>


            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductName") %>'></asp:Label>
            </td>

            <td>
                 <asp:Label ID="lblPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Price") %>'></asp:Label>
            </td>

            <td>
                  <asp:Label ID="lblSum" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Summary") %>'></asp:Label>
            </td>

            <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblPic" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("picPath") %>'></asp:Label>
            </td>

            <td>
            <asp:HiddenField Value='<%# Eval("picPath") %>' ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" />
            </td>


            </tr>
           </ItemTemplate>



    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

the c# code:

```
protected void ExampleRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        HiddenField hf = e.Item.FindControl("HiddenField1") as HiddenField;
        if (hf != null)
        {
            string val = hf.Value;
            Image img = e.Item.FindControl("Image1") as Image;
            img.ImageUrl =   val + ".jpg";
        }
    }
```

its not working, I'm missing something- I dont know.
please help me,
thanx

Answer (score 0):

You can try with - based on `Server.MapPath` in order to define relative path

```
img.ImageUrl = Server.MapPath(val + ".jpg");
```

Comment: no it doesnt help.
in the db should i store the full path of the image?